# What's the process for submitting work to a GitHub open source project after completing an issue locally?

Tags: git, github

I am new to open source and Git. I am currently trying to contribute to a project. They gave me an issue to work on and I have done the work at my local end, but now I want to give this to them (like other people are giving their work and the project manager is approving them and finally resolving the issue). I want to submit this work to them, otherwise my whole work will be wasted. I did the work by cloning their repo, and applying the required changes in vscode.

Comment: You want to submit a "Pull Request" with your changes. Github has extensive documentation around this so it probably doesn't make sense for someone to paraphrase it into an answer here.